# How does Spring Framework maintain the quality control for every release

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-security

HI i would like to understand How are Spring Framework is  Tested (regression/ security / new features/ performance), does the code get reviewed is manual or tool based, are there any development guidelines, published by pivotal.

I am always intrigued with so many contributors for a particular release from across the globe, and the product being massive how do the team ensure code of an optimum quality.

Comment: Online a handful of people are allowed to commit to master and there are (strict) contribution guidelines. Everything goes through pull requests and those are being  verified and checked by the core committers and polished or commented on to improve the quality.

Comment: @M.Deinum thanks for the feedback. Are you aware of any published guidelines. Also who does security and performance test for each release etc..

Comment: There aren't performance tests (afaik) and security isn't either. Security issues are reported through another way (not in the public JIRA) and when fixed published on the blog together with a CVE.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each Spring project has a handful of committers. Almost everything goes through pull-requests, see the [Contributing](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/blob/master/CONTRIBUTING.md) documentation on Github).

Next to that there are also strict [formatting guidelines](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/wiki/Code-Style) (so things are consistent). [Codacy](https://app.codacy.com/project/Spring-Projects/spring-framework/dashboard) verifies and checks each pull request for known coding issues.

Before the pull request is being merged to master a core committer verifies and polishes it. They also follow a [guide for merging pull requests](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/wiki/Manually-merging-pull-requests).

Finally there are [~ 19000 of tests](https://build.spring.io/browse/SPR-JDK9) which are run on each commit as well as [performance tests](https://build.spring.io/browse/SPR-PERF) for known hotspots.

Security issues are [reported through Pivotal](https://pivotal.io/security) and don't show up on the public JIRA (to prevent early disclosure and attacks being possible). When fixed they are generally announced specially on the [release blog](https://spring.io/blog/2018/06/14/spring-project-vulnerability-reports-published) including links to the CVE reports.

Answer (score 0):

You can read the contributing guidelines and documentation on spring repository. [Here it is!](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/tree/master/src/docs/asciidoc)